# How to using transformation features from linear to gaussian

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression, gaussian

[ASK]
I am working on a lecture but I do not understand and still lack of knowledge about how to change the transformation feature from linear to gaussian, I have searched for information but still haven't found the right one and still lack of knowledge about python, below is a python script that I made with linear regression, and I want to transform features with Gaussian, please help to write the script for feature transformation

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
df1=data[['time', 'Cases']]

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
df1 = shuffle(df1,random_state=0)


X=np.array(df1[['time']])
y=np.array(df1[['Cases']])
X_train = X[:-10]
X_test = X[-10:]
y_train = y[:-10]
y_test = y[-10:]
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)



print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
# The mean squared error
print('Mean squared error: %.2f'
% mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
# The coefficient of determination: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Coefficient of determination: %.2f'
% r2_score(y_test, y_pred))

# Plot outputs
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test,  color='black')
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train,  color='black')
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you should start with [GPR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62118428/how-to-using-transformation-fiture-from-linear-to-gaussian). See the examples and try to mimic it with your data.

Comment: hy @Anwarvic can you show me the example for GPR and mimic cause im realy realy dont know

thanks